# refreshApex in lwc doesn't seem to work

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, refresh

I have a custom lwc that works with refresh apex. I want a method to be refreshed from another function

js:

```
import {refreshApex} from '@salesforce/apex';
import initData from '@salesforce/apex/myClass.initData';

export default class Tm_GDPRInfoSignatureLWC LightningElement {

    wiredGDPRresult;
    @track myData;

    @wire(initData , {recordId : '$recordID'}) wiredInitData(result) {
        this.wiredGDPRresult = result;
        //data retrieved
        if(result.data) {
            console.log('entered');
            this.myData = result.data;
            console.log('finished');
        }
        //error
        else if(result.error){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result.error));
        }
    }

    refreshData(){
        return refreshApex(this.wiredGDPRresult);
    }
}
```

And it's working find when initializing the lwc but whenever I call refreshData it's doing nothing (not even displaying console.logs())

Is there something I'm setting wrong or do I need to call refreshApex in a different way?

**EDIT**

I'm calling my function whenever I receive a custom event from another lwc. And it's receiving that event but `refreshApex` doesn't do anything

```
connectedCallback(){
    registerListener('refreshData', this.refreshData, this);
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you call refreshData and a snippet of the template too? (I see you made a change for the import usages)

Comment: @PhilW I just updated the question and add where my `refreshData` methods i being called from. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will actually work but as its cacheable (or cached to be precise) apex method, the wired function ***imperativeWire*** will be invoked ONLY if the apex method response changes/modified. However every time you invoke `refreshData`, you will see the apex log - can be tested in developer console.

For testing, you can return some accounts:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<Account> getAccountsList() {
    return [SELECT Id, Name, Phone FROM Account LIMIT 10];
},
```

Then use wired function to get these accounts in LWC component.

Then when you change some field value in one of these accounts and invoke `refreshData` you will see the console log in LWC also.

Comment: You're right. It's only entering if my response has changed. Thanks, I didn't notice that at first try!

Comment: Nice....I too needed this