# refreshApex not always working

Tags: apex, javascript, lightning-web-components, refreshapex

I have a parent LWC with a list of records and a child LWC which allows the user to perform actions on the record.

The child uses `dispatchEvent` and `CustomEvent` to notify the parent after changes have been made to the record, so that the parent can refresh the list of records.

Unfortunately, `refreshApex` in the parent is not always working...

Here is the code.....

**parent component**

```
<template>
  // contains a list of records, removed for brevity 
  <c-child-record-detail onback={handleBack} record-id={recordId}></c-child-record-detail>
</template>
```

**parent JavaScript**

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from "lwc";
import { refreshApex } from "@salesforce/apex";
import getRecords from "@salesforce/apex/MyController.getRecords";

export default class MyLWC extends LightningElement {

    records;
    wiredResult;
    records; // used to render
    recordList; // used to store the original set from the server
    filterValue = "";
    recordId;

    @wire(getRecords) wiredRecords(value) {

        this.wiredResult = value;
        const { data, error } = value;
        if (data) {
            this.error = null;
            this.recordList = data;
            this.filterList();
        } else if (error) { ... }
    }

    refreshList() {
        return refreshApex(this.wiredResult);
    }

    handleBack() {
        this.recordId = null;
        this.refreshList();
    }

    handleFilterChange(event) {
        this.filterValue = event.detail.value;
        this.filterList();
    }

    filterList() {
        switch (this.filterValue) {
            case "Status1":
                this.records = this.recordList.reduce(this.exampleReducer, []);
                break;

            // many other cases removed for brevity 
        }
    }

    exampleReducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => {
        if (currentValue.Status__c === "example") {
            accumulator.push(currentValue);
            return accumulator;
        }
        return accumulator;
    };

    // many other reducers, removed for brevity 

    handleRowClick(event) {
        this.recordId = event.currentTarget.dataset.recordId;
    }
}
```

I've tried very hard to reduce the code example down without losing its essence.

You will notice that I am doing client side filtering using `reduce`.

The `c-child-record-detail` component is reasonably complex, but the problem related to two buttons which are used to *finish* looking at the record, so we can go back to the list.

**child component**

**child button A JavaScript**

```
handleButtonAClick() {
    updateAsSomeSubStatus({ recordId: this.recordId}).then(result => {
        if (result === true) {
            this.backToList();
        }
    }).catch(error => this.handleError(error));
}
```

**child button A Apex**

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Boolean updateAsSomeSubStatus(Id recordId) {
   try {
       Opportunity record = new Opportunity(Id = recordId);
       record.Sub_Status__c = "SomeSubStatus";
       update record;
       return true;
   } catch (Exception cause) {
      throw AuraHandledExceptionFactory.create(cause);
   }
}
```

**child button B JavaScript**

```
handleButtonBClick() {
    updateAsStatusAndSubStatus({ recordId: this.recordId}).then(result => {
        if (result === true) {
            this.backToList();
        }
    }).catch(error => this.handleError(error));
}
```

**child button B Apex**

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Boolean updateAsStatusAndSubStatus(Id recordId) {
   try {
       Opportunity record = new Opportunity(Id = recordId);
       record.StageName = "SomeStageName";
       record.Sub_Status__c = null;
       update record;
       return true;
   } catch (Exception cause) {
      throw AuraHandledExceptionFactory.create(cause);
   }
}
```

**Both** buttons work, and the record is updated successfully.

**Both** buttons return a `result` of `true`;

**Both** buttons call the `backToList` JavaScript method

```
backToList() {
    this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("back"));
}
```

The List only only refreshes correctly for button A.

I also have a refresh button on the list which calls `refreshApex` and no matter how many times I click on it, it does not get the refresh records.

I have to do a hard refresh of the page!

**Question**

1. What is going wrong?
2. How can I fix it such that `refreshApex` consistently works?
3. What other ways are there to clear the cache such that `wire` will re-fire?

Comment: Dunno if it relates to your issue but note that wire functions are only invoked if the new data fetched from the server after a refreshApex has changed. Take a look at [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/282118/refreshapex-in-lwc-doesnt-seem-to-work/282122#282122) for more info.

Comment: I suspect this is what you're seeing. The solution is to switch to imperative invocation :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my scenario, I was calling `refreshApex` which was calling an Apex method `getRecords` which returned a `List<Opportunity>`

But I was going from a record list size of `1` to `0` and my Apex method:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<Opportunity> getRecords() {

    List<Opportunity> records = [SELECT ... FROM Opportunity WHERE ...];

    if (records.size() == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    return records;
}
```

If there were no records, I was returning `null` which meant the lightning framework was not updating the cache.

When I changed the method to return an empty list it worked.

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<Opportunity> getRecords() {

    List<Opportunity> records = [SELECT ... FROM Opportunity WHERE ...];

    if (records.size() == 0) {
        return new List<Opportunity>(); // <-- HERE
    }
    return records;
}
```

Which I guess can be further simplified down to:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<Opportunity> getRecords() {

    return [SELECT ... FROM Opportunity WHERE ...];
}
```

Comment: If you could accept this answer, it would mark it as solved, which would help keep the site nice and tidy.